# Find the angle $x$ in the figure below.

Tags: geometry

For reference: In the figure, $ABCDEF$, $AMNF$ and $FTN$ are regular polygons. Find $"x"$.

[image]

My progress:
I marked all the Angles I could find but the main one is still missing

[image]

Comment: We can find the angles $\angle FAT$ and $\angle ABM$ using isosceles triangles then we should be able to get $x$ using the inner angle sum in the triangle $AIB$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\triangle ABM$ is isosceles so $\angle AMB = \angle ABM = \cfrac{180^ \circ - 30^\circ}{2} = 75^ \circ$

Say side of hexagon is $a$ and perp from $T$ to $FN$ is $TH$ and to $AM$ is $TG$, then

$TH = FT \sin 60^ \circ = \cfrac{\sqrt3  a}{2}$

$TG = a - \cfrac{\sqrt3  a}{2}$

$\tan (\angle TAM) = \cfrac{TG}{AM/2} = 2 - \sqrt3$

$\implies \angle TAM = 15^ \circ$

So, $x = \angle AIB = 180^ \circ - 75^ \circ - 45^ \circ = 60^ \circ$

---

Without trigonometry, note that $\triangle AFT$ is isosceles with $\angle FAT = 75^0$ so $\angle MAT = 15^0$. That leads to the answer.

Comment: I think you should use ```$60^\circ$``` --> $60^\circ$

Comment: @Algebrology thank you! I will remember it now.

Comment: @MathLover   grateful as always for the help

Answer (score 1):

$$\angle BAM =\angle AFT = 120^\circ-90^\circ=30^\circ $$

$$\angle ABM = \angle AMB = \angle FAT = \angle FTA = \frac{180^\circ-30^\circ}{2}=75^\circ$$

$$\angle MAT = 120^\circ- (75^\circ+30^\circ)=15^\circ$$

$$\angle AMB =x+15^\circ=75^\circ$$

$$x=60^\circ$$

Comment: &\measuredangle BMN = $30^o$? Aren't you mistaken?

Comment: @peta arantes , $\angle BAM = 30^\circ$, i edited